# how to return empty field in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to check incomplete record and identify the bad record in Spark.

```
eg. sample test.txt file, it is in record format, columns separated by \t

L1C1    L1C2    L1C3    L1C4
L2C1    L2C2    L2C3    
L3C1    L3C2    L3C3    L3C4

scala> sc.textFile("test.txt").filter(_.split("\t").length < 4).collect.foreach(println)
L2C1    L2C2    L2C3
```

The second line is printing as having less number of columns.
How should i parse without ignoring the empty column after  in second line

Comment: sc.textFile("test.txt") will create RDD[String] not the DataFrame (columns)
Could you please add your expected output?

Comment: i was trying to do basic check for the file, if there are any incomplete record(less tab separated fields), another case if the record is ended by \ , it will continue in next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the split string in scala removes trailing empty substrings.
The behavior is similar to Java, to let all the substrings checked we can call as
"L2C1   L2C2    L2C3    ".split("\t",-1)